# how to use timer to control on off duration of a LED in raspberry pi

Tags: python-2.7, timer, raspberry-pi2

I want to use the timer to control the on / off duration of a LED . I wrote the code as below,  but it does not run.

```
def main ():
    LED =27
    GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)

    while (True):
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            todayon = now.replace(hour = 17, minute=47, second =0, microsecond =0)
            todayoff = now.replace(hour = 17, minute=48, second =0, microsecond =0)
            turnon = now>todayon
            turnoff = now>todayoff

            if(turnon == True):
                    GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.LOW)
                    time.sleep(1)

            if(turnoff == True):
                    GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't run (doing nothing at all), it's probably because you never call `main`

In that case add the following lines at the bottom:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Beside that you need to setup the GPIO to use port numbers or pin numbers.
With `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` you set the mode to port numbers, so GPIO port number 27 will be used as an output when you call `GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)`.

The complete script should now look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import datetime
import RP1.GPIO as GPIO

def main ():
    LED =27
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)

    while (True):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        todayon = now.replace(hour = 17, minute=47, second =0, microsecond =0)
        todayoff = now.replace(hour = 17, minute=48, second =0, microsecond =0)
        turnon = now>todayon and now<todayoff
        turnoff = now>todayoff

        if(turnon == True):
                GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)

        if(turnoff == True):
                GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Comment: I want to 17h47 it flashes and 17h48 the LED light.  17h48 LED still flashing

Comment: I didn't pay attention to that part after finding the other errors. Please reconsider the logic of the program.Before 17:48 only `turnon` is true, after 17:48 both, `turnon` and `turnoff` are true. You could set `turnon` true if it's later than `todayon` and earlier than `turnoff`. I edit the code to show you..

Comment: I was wrong
Can you help me, how can I work that way?
For example: I want 17h, the LED blinks and 18h the LED is on.
Thank you very much.
Please help me.

Comment: Kindly accept my answer, as the original question is answered. If you want other times then set other times in the program, I don't see a problem there.

Comment: sorry
I do not understand what you mean :((

Comment: Yes
wait for me
Sorry, because I'm new to use so do not know much

Comment: the second part is: you want to change the time when the LED blinks or is just on or off. So you just have to change the time. For example in `todayon = now.replace(hour = 17, minute=47, second =0, microsecond =0)`you change minute to zero. And for `todayoff`you change hour to 18 and minute to 0. Just adjust the values to your needs.

Comment: oh.
Not so. I still can not do it. I want to timer for LED operation. My example is: 17h LED flashing (same as 17h47) And 18h LED turn on (same as 17h48)

Comment: do you understand what I mean

Comment: or do you want the LED to blink at 17:00 just for a minute, then turn off and then turn on for a minute at 18:00? Whatever you want, please read the code carefully, consider the logic of it and make your changes. The basics  are there, you just have to change the logic a little bit. But that's really something you should do on your own.Change something, try it, and if it doesn't work change again. That's your job as a programmer.

Comment: thank you. I tried other ways but it was not. Since I first worked with it, I did not know much. And here is the exercise I have to do. I'm not a programmer :))

Comment: thank you. I tried other ways but it was not. Since I first worked with it, I did not know much. And here is the exercise I have to do. I'm not a programmer :))

Comment: The thing I want is: I want to use the timer mode. At 17h the LED flashes and at 18h the LED turns on.
You can help me . :((